# Data wont insert into MySQL database for registration in login / registration form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, registration

I am specifically getting a self defined error when I try to register a new account - 'We are unable to create a new account at this time due to technical errors.'

I set this error to be echoed if the information isn't being posted to my MySQL database. I have no idea why its not being posted

So the error is with the registration part (or the session part) but I have posted all relevant code here.

This is all contained in a html which is working fine.

This is the php code at the VERY START (above !DOCTYPE html) that starts my session off.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])){

header("Location: profile.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

This is the code for the login form:

```
            <ul>
                <li>
<input type="text" name="username" id="uname_log"         value="" placeholder="Username" class="required requiredField Email fg-input text fg-fw" />
                </li>
                <li>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password_log" value="" placeholder="Password" class="required requiredField  fg-input text fg-fw" />
                </li>
                <li>
               <div class="chkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="true"/> Remember me</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="clear"></div>                       
                    <input class="submit signin_btn fg-btn blue large inline fg-fw bold" type="submit" name="submit2" value="Sign In"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
<?php

        if (isset($_POST["submit2"])) {
            $username =$_POST['username'];
            $password =$_POST['password'];

            $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'U7wQkQ**') or die(mysqli_error());
            mysqli_select_db($connect, 'test6') or die("Cannot select database");

            $query=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE username ='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
            $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if ($numrows!=0){
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    $dbusername=$row['username'];
                    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
                }
            if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword){



            $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $username;



            }
            } else {
                echo "Invalid username or password";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

This is the code for the registration form:

```
<form action="" id="freesigninForm" class="freesigninForm" method="post">
                 <ul>

                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="reg_email" value="" placeholder="Username" class="required requiredField Email fg-input text fg-fw" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="reg_password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="required requiredField Password fg-input text fg-fw" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" id="reg_password2" onkeyup="checkPasswordMatch();" value="" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="required requiredField Password fg-input text fg-fw" />
                </li>

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <li>
                    <input style="display: none;" id="reg_check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="YES" checked/>  
                    <span style="display: none;"><a href='http://www.formget.com/terms-conditions/' target='_blank'>I agree with terms and conditions</a></span>
                    <button id="buttonActivate" class="submit fg-btn blue large inline fg-fw bold" type="submit" name="submit" >Create Account</button>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];  
$password = $_POST['password'];

$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'U7wQkQ**') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'test6') or die("Cannot select database");

$query=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE username='".$username."'");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numrows== 0){

    $sql ="INSERT INTO test (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";


    $result=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if ($result) {
        echo "Account successfully created";

    } else { 
        echo "We are unable to create a new account at this time due to technical errors.";
    }

    } else {
        echo "Username already exists. Please try again with a unique username!";

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Instead of your custom message output the error that caused it http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. You also are open to SQL injections and should be hashing the passwords.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

YESS I figured it out with the help of chris85.

Basically once I outpur mysqli errors using  echo mysqli_error($connect); in my code, I got the an error saying Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'.

So basically my database was trying to overwrite the primary key data each time (I didn't mention it but this code worked yesterday but wasnt working today and I didn't understand why)

Once I set my primary key (ID) to A_I or auto increment, the tables are updating :D

Comment: That's one bug fixed, about six to go.